# Entity Framework, update and saving changes on an object retrieved with SelectMany does not work

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Situation 1: //In this case the Workout is not removed from db

```
Season season = dbContext.Seasons.Find(58);
var ps1 = season.PlannerSeason;
PlannerWorkout pworkoutToRemove = ps1.Weeks.SelectMany(w => w.WeekDays.SelectMany(wd => wd.PlannerWorkouts)).Where(pw => pw.WorkoutID == 3615).FirstOrDefault();
bool isRemoved = ps1.Weeks.SelectMany(w => w.WeekDays.SelectMany(wd => wd.PlannerWorkouts)).ToList().Remove(pworkoutToRemove);

dbContext.SaveChanges(); //does not work
```

Situation 2 : //Here the exact same Workout is retrieved and remove from db. it works

```
Season season = dbContext.Seasons.Find(58);
var ps1 = season.PlannerSeason;
PlannerWeek pweek = ps1.Weeks.Find(w => w.WeekNo == 14);
PlannerWeekDay pwd = pweek.WeekDays.Find(d => d.DayNo == 1);
PlannerWorkout pworkoutToRemove = pwd.PlannerWorkouts.Find(pw => pw.WorkoutID == 3615);
bool isRemoved = pwd.PlannerWorkouts.Remove(pworkoutToRemove);

dbContext.SaveChanges(); //works
```

Does it make a difference to retrieve a single object via SelectMany ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that you retrieve the object with `SelectMany`, but here

```
bool isRemoved = ps1.Weeks.SelectMany(w => w.WeekDays.SelectMany(wd => wd.PlannerWorkouts))
    .ToList() // <--
    .Remove(pworkoutToRemove);
```

which is equivalent of:

```
var tempList = ps1.Weeks.SelectMany(w => w.WeekDays.SelectMany(wd => wd.PlannerWorkouts))
    .ToList();
bool isRemoved = tempList.Remove(pworkoutToRemove);
```

In other words, you are creating a temporary list and remove the object from that list, rather than from the parent collection as in the working example.

In case you have inverse navigation property to the parent `WeekDay`, you can use this instead

```
bool isRemoved = pworkoutToRemove != null &&
    pworkoutToRemove.WeekDay.PlannerWorkouts.Remove(pworkoutToRemove);
```

or you can directly remove it from the corresponding `DbSet`:

```
bool isRemoved = false;
if (pworkoutToRemove != null)
{
    dbContext.PlannerWorkouts.Remove(pworkoutToRemove);
    isRemoved = true;
}
```

or set the entity state to `Deleted`:

```
bool isRemoved = false;
if (pworkoutToRemove != null)
{
    dbContext.Entry(pworkoutToRemove).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    isRemoved = true;
}
```